# How do I install Flashtool 0.91 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04

http://www.flashtool.net/download.php

try to give me a guide or something(with pictures or a video if possible)

Comment: How about this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1463986

Comment: Flashtool-xperia for 13.04 is availble in Launchpad. You can try with it by following command. Certain packages which for 13.04 works on trusty. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:trebelnik-stefina/myppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install flashtool-xperia`

Comment: i got this-E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 4):

Check first if Java is already installed:

```
java -version
```

If the reply states a positive one (as shown below)

```
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

Then you're in luck mate! You can continue to the next step

If not,then;  (I use WebUpd8 Team's PPA for ease of installing)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer
```

After installing Java7,extract the FlashTool tar.gz,then the tar to some folder (In this case,I will use Desktop)

```
sudo bash
cd Desktop
cd FlashTool
./ FlashTool
```

enjoy and remember - Exit the terminal after exiting Flashtool

Answer (score 2):

Try this but may not work.

## GUI

[Click here](https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/myppa/+build/4270030/+files/flashtool-xperia_0.9.10.1-2~raring_all.deb) to download the .deb file.  Open the .deb file in a .deb installer tool like Ubuntu Software Center, or Gdebi as a few examples.  Than Install it.

## LUI

```
cd /tmp
wget https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/myppa/+build/4270030/+files/flashtool-xperia_0.9.10.1-2~raring_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i flashtool-xperia_0.9.10.1-2~raring_all.deb
```

Comment: ok,installed it...wht should i do next?

Comment: @user3264255 than opem it. If you don't see it in the dash, than press `CTRL + ALT + T` on the keyboard and type this command in `flashtool-xperia`

Comment: /usr/bin/flashtool-xperia: 6: /usr/bin/flashtool-xperia: gksu: not found

Comment: is it ok if i use wine?

Comment: @user3264255 if it runs under wine, then yea.

Comment: @user3264255 I couldn't find it in the Wine App DB.

Comment: of course you can't find it...i extraced the exe from the windows version

Answer (score -2):

someone with Flashtool in their machines please just follow this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Personal and add Flashtool to the Ubuntu repositories

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This answer does not address the question directly: "How to install Flashtool". It would be more suited as a comment.