# Install or run FlashTool?

Tags: java, tar

Okay,

I've downloaded "flashtool-0.9.18.5-linux.tar.7z" from the Xda Forums ( http://xda-forum.blogspot.nl/2015/03/how-to-install-xperia-firmware-using.html ) and I have tried to run "x10flasher.jar" contained therein by double-clicking it, by selecting "Open with OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime" and by selecting "Open with Oracle 7 Java Runtime" (after selecting "Properties-->Permissions-->Allow executing file as a program" first, of course), however none of these actions does anything.

So, back to the beginning.

Then I tried extracting flashtool-0.9.18.5-linux.tar.7z (so I now have "flashtool-0.9.18.5-linux.tar.7z" and "flashtool-0.9.18.5-linux.tar" on my Desktop) and following the instructions at [How do I install Flashtool 0.91 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464169/how-do-i-install-flashtool-0-91-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts) ...

When I type:

```
cd Desktop
```

Termianl tells me:

```
bash: cd: FlashTool: No such file or directory
```

When I extract "flashtool-0.9.18.5-linux" (so I now have "flashtool-0.9.18.5-linux.tar.7z", "flashtool-0.9.18.5-linux.tar" and "FlashTool" (folder) on my Desktop) and then type:

```
cd FlashTool
```

Everything seems to go fine, but then when I type:

```
./ FlashTool
```

Terminal tells me:

```
bash: ./: Is a directory
```

I suspect the problem and the resolution is something simple, but whatever the problem and the solution is, I just can't seem to nail it... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Open a terminal by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

Run the following commands:

```
sudo -i
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall p7zip-full
cd /home/user_name/Desktop
7z e flashtool-0.9.18.5-linux.tar.7z
tar -xvf flashtool-0.9.18.5-linux.tar
cd /home/user_name/Desktop/FlashTool
chmod +x FlashToll
chmod +x FlashToolConsole
./FlashTool
```

Comment: That works... Except it now says "Please move /home/gregoryopera/Desktop/FlashTool/firmwares content to /root/.flashTool/firmwares". How do I do that?

Comment: sudo mv /home/gregoryopera/Desktop/FlashTool/firmwares/* /root/.flashTool/firmwares

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a space between ./ and FlashTool.
Just "./FlashTool", not "./ FlashTool"